# Instantiating a set of classes from a list

Tags: python, class, oop, python-2.7, instantiation

I'm relatively new at Python, using 2.7. This is something that seemed like it should work, but doesn't.

I want to create an instance of class Game with multiple instances of class Player. The user instantiates Game, specifying a number of players, e.g., game = Game(3). I want to call the Player instances p1, p2, etc.

I start with a method that creates a list of names

```
def getPlayerList(self):
    self.playerlist = []
    for p in range (self.numplayers):
        self.playerlist.append("p" + str(p+1))
    return self.playerlist
```

For 3 players, this produces a list of 3 strings:

```
self.playerlist = [p1, p2, p3]
```

Now I want to create 3 instances of Player, assigned to p1, p2, and p3. This seemed to be the easiest way to do it:

```
def initPlayers(self):
    self.getPlayerList()
    for i in self.playerlist:
        i = Player(i)  # doesn't work
    return
```

This code does loop thru Player instantiation 3 times, but "i" does not get replaced with strings p1, p2, and p3.  So, for example

```
p1.name
```

is undefined.

For that matter, so is

```
i.name
```

If I test other code with this for loop, it works with the expected substitution. For example:

```
for i in self.playerlist:
    print i

p1
p2
p3
```

But

```
i = Player(i)
```

does not turn into instantiation

```
p1 = Player("p1")
```

I can't figure out why this doesn't this work, and don't know how else I should be doing this, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are over-complicating this. Trying to dynamically generate variable names is usually a bad idea; use a dictionary instead:

```
players = {i:Player(i) for i in self.playerlist}
```

Or, even simpler, a list, where you can access players by index:

```
players = [Player(i) for i in self.playerlist]
```

All you are doing in your current loop is assigning a new `Player` object to the `for` loop variable `i`, which is then immediately discarded when the loop iterates.

Comment: Exactly. In this case, a list is enough too: `p = [Player(i) for i in xrange(n)]`. Then use them like `p[0]`, `p[1]`, etc.

Comment: I already have the list version; simply using `xrange` won't give the correct player names.

Answer (score 1):

Print is somewhat tricky because it can hide differences between different kind of objects that are printed the same way.

The content of `self.playerlist` is not `p1`, `p2` and `p3`, but `"p1"`, `"p2"` and `"p3"`. In other words your list contains three strings.

Would you really expect

```
 i = "p1"
 i = 2
```

to assign 2 to a new variable `p1` or just to assign a new value `2` to variable `i`?

Creating "new variables" at runtime is possible in Python (for example using `globals()[i]=2`) but very rarely needed. Using just a dictionary or a list instead of using variables is a much better option:

```
self.players = [Player(i) for i in range(3)]
```

then for example instead of `p1.draw()` you use `self.players[0].draw()` and you get the extremely important advantage that you can also simply say `self.players[i].draw()` to access the generic `i`-th player.